# Elide/text-overflow/ellipses text in Webkit

Tags: qt, qtwebkit, qwebview

It is possible to configure the **QWebView** to work with **"Elide"** disabled (equivalent to `Qt::ElideNone`)?

The **"Elide"** graphic texts being compressed (elieded) to fit inside the select.

**Example:**
[image]

I wish the entire text to be displayed when clicked on comobox (selectbox). Is it possible?

Thanks.

**[edit]**
I think it may be the way the styleSheet (qt):

```
QComboBox QAbstractItemView {
   ...
}
```

I just do not know which property to use styleSheet disable "elited".

Maybe something like this:

```
QComboBox QAbstractItemView {
   elided: none;
  ...or...
   elide: none;
}
```

Anyone know a link with all properties stylesheets used in QT (I searched but did not find)?

**[edit 2]**

I tried `white-space: pre;` and `white-space: nowrap;` that seems the most logical, but does not work with `QAbstractItemView`, will be the selector is another?

Comment: Alternative solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20554940/qcombobox-pop-up-expanding-and-qtwebkit/20909625#20909625

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the `textElideMode` property by adding a rule `QComboBox QAbstractItemView { qproperty-textElideMode: ElideNone }` (See [Style Sheet Syntax - Setting QObject properties](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/stylesheet-syntax.html#setting-qobject-properties)) but it will only clip the text on the right without extending the drop-down box.

According to the code source, the list view adjust its size to its content when it is displayed as a popup which is done by adding this in the stylesheet:

```
QComboBox {
    combobox-popup: true;
    // To make room for the possible scrollbar 
    // (the value has to match the scrollbar width of the current style/platform)
    padding-right: 20px;
}
```

Outside that popup mode, the width of the drop-down box is taken from the list view minimum size (or from the `min-width` css property of the `QAbstractItemView`), but there doesn't seem to be a way, with css only, to automatically adjust the size of the drop-down box to the content of the list.

Comment: Nice link (+1 for you), so I'll try and get me back. Grateful.

Comment: I tested Better Today "combobox-popup", it works well, the size actually accompanies the content, but always a stretch gets cut. What could it be?

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento I don't know what you mean by "always a stretch gets cut". Could you post a screen shot of the problem ?

Comment: I solved the problem for "QWebViews" using "padding": `QComboBox {
        combobox-popup: true;
        padding: 1px 18px 1px 3px;
     }` source: http://harmattan-dev.nokia.com/docs/library/html/qt4/stylesheet-examples.html#customizing-qcombobox (note: I edited your answer with this data and marked it for granted, grateful for the help.)