# "QComboBox Pop-up" expanding and QtWebkit

Tags: c++, qt, qtwebkit, qcombobox, qtgui

In Firefox/Chrome/InternetExplorer/Safari/Opera pop-ups from the *combobox* expand as the content, see Firefox picture:

[image: Firefox combobox]

`QComboBox` pop-up does not expand the content. *Pop-ups* are limited by the size of `QComboBox`, see *QWebView* picture:

[image: Qt and QtWebkit combobox]

So I implemented the *QComboBox::showPopup*:

```
void newQComboBox::showPopup() {
    int width = this->width();
    this->view()->setTextElideMode( Qt::ElideNone );

    const int iconSize = this->iconSize().width();
    const QFontMetrics fontMetrics = this->fontMetrics();
    const int j = this->count();

    for( int i=0; i < j; ++i ) {
        const int textWidth = fontMetrics.width( this->itemText(i) + "WWW" );
        if (this->itemIcon(i).isNull()) {
            width = qMax(width, textWidth);
        } else {
            width = qMax(width, textWidth + iconSize);
        }
    }

    QStyleOptionComboBox opt;
    this->initStyleOption(&opt);
    QSize size(width, 0);
    size = this->style()->sizeFromContents(QStyle::CT_ComboBox, &opt, size, this);

    this->view()->setFixedWidth( width );

    QComboBox::showPopup();
}
```

Is there any way to modify (reimplement) the `QComboBox::showPopup` of `QWebViews` (QtWebkit)?

**Qt-BUG (suggestion):** https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-35771

Comment: What style are you using? How the popup is shown, and if the matching view has the same size of the combobox or is allowed to be bigger, depends totally on the style used.

Comment: ... which also tells you how to fix it: see `QComboBox::showPopup` code and use a QProxyStyle diverting the right calls. Of course, all of this is assuming that QWebView is using a QComboBox, and not something that *resembles* a QComboBox...

Comment: Have you access to the HTML file which you expect to shows this `ComboBox`, or you have no control for what is being showed by the `QWebView`? Because I implemented a ComboBox that uses your custom `QComboBox` into a `QWebView` but it only work if the HTML page use a specific code, not the `<select>` code to show the `ComboBox`.

Comment: @user2014561 I am developing a browser and not a specific application. I need to access any site work like Firefox/InternetExplorer/Chrome browsers (I mean the combobox, like the screenshot I posted: http://i.stack.imgur.com/VOn9w.png ). Thanks

Comment: @peppe Thanks to your comment I could find the solution.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I solved using [`QProxyStyle`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qproxystyle.html) class, example:

```
#include <QProxyStyle>
#include <QAbstractItemView>
#include <QComboBox>

class myProxyStyle : public QProxyStyle
{

public:
    int styleHint(StyleHint hint, const QStyleOption *option, const QWidget *widget, QStyleHintReturn *returnData) const
    {
        if(hint == QStyle::SH_ComboBox_Popup) {
            const QComboBox *combo = (QComboBox *) widget;//cast to QComboBox
            const QObjectList a = combo->children();
            const int j = a.count();
            QAbstractItemView *view = 0;
            QString className = "";
            bool hasView = false;

            /*
            at this point I have not used combo->view() because he "crash" the application without explanation
            so I had to make a loop to find the "view"
            */
            for (int i = 0; i < j; ++i) {
                const QObjectList b = a.at(i)->children();
                const int y = b.count();

                for (int x = 0; x < y; ++x) {
                    className = b.at(x)->metaObject()->className();

                    if (className == "QComboBoxListView") {
                        view = (QAbstractItemView *) b.at(x);
                        hasView = true;
                        break;
                    }
                }

                if (hasView) {
                    break;
                }
            }

            if (hasView) {
                const int iconSize = combo->iconSize().width();
                const QFontMetrics fontMetrics1 = view->fontMetrics();
                const QFontMetrics fontMetrics2 = combo->fontMetrics();
                const int j = combo->count();
                int width = combo->width(); //default width

                for (int i = 0; i < j; ++i) {
                    const int textWidth = qMax(
                        fontMetrics1.width(combo->itemText(i) + "WW"),
                        fontMetrics2.width(combo->itemText(i) + "WW")
                    );

                    if(combo->itemIcon(i).isNull()) {
                        width = qMax(width, textWidth);
                    } else {
                        width = qMax(width, textWidth + iconSize);
                    }
                }

                view->setFixedWidth(width);
            }
        }

        return QProxyStyle::styleHint(hint, option, widget, returnData);
    }
};
```

how to use:

You must apply in [`QApplication`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtwidgets/qapplication.html) (usually file `main.cpp`):

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    a.setStyle(new myProxyStyle);//set ProxyStyle

    return a.exec();
}
```

---

[*@peppe*](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1873944/peppe) thanks to your comment I got the solution

Answer (score -2):

Please try to make use of the setMinimumWidth function and pass the max width you have calculated. it should work
    **ui.comboBox->view()->setMinimumWidth(width);**
for more detail please go through https://qt-project.org/forums/viewthread/26388 link

Comment: The combo box is displayed by the web view. The author already has an implementation that works, the question is how to get the web view to use his implementation.

Comment: I agree with @Kuba here.